# Get Values from inherited when base type is given back

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, inherited

Situation:
IdentityUser is inherited by AppUser.

AppUser has a few properties more.((int)ExClientNr and (string)Category)

On top

```
UserManager <IdentityUser> userManager
```

request

`var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);`

When I hover over user (of type IdentityUser) in runtime, I see all AppUser properties with values in the list.

But when I type

```
var exClientNr = User.ExClientNr;
```

the field ExClientNr or Category is not recognized in the intellisense.All fields of IdentityUser are of cause.

User.Getype() gives me {Name="AppUser" FullName="namespace.Models.AppUser"} so it is even aware of his type.

> Question:
>   Can someone tell me how to get the value from those extra properties from this object.

Comment: Why `UserManager <IdentityUser> userManager` and not `UserManager <AppUser> userManager`?

Comment: An object has a type identity.  Variables are of a particular type.  So you can write `Base baseObj = new Sub();` (assuming `Sub` inherits from `Base`).  As far as the compiler knows, the `baseObj` variable is a reference to an object of type `Base`.  The object itself is of type `Sub` (which makes it a `Base` as well).  If you are passing around `Base`-typed variables, but you need access to the `Sub`-ishness of `Sub`-typed objects, you can use `if (baseObj is Sub subObj) {subObj.SubCall();}`.  That, however, is usually a code-smell

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic UserManager with the right type:

```cs
UserManager <AppUser> userManager
```

Or cast your user in run-time:

```cs
var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
var exClientNr = (user as AppUser)?.ExClientNr;
```

Comment: Anton Thank you. 
With the first option I'm not able to use. Just after this code I login with the signin manager  who needs a IdentityUser as param.

The second option gives a convertion error.

Comment: You can use `SignInManager<AppUser>`. Moreover, if your `AppUser` is inherited from `IdentityUser`, you can pass it event in SignManager with IdentityUser type

Comment: And that's where the error comes, how strange it sounds, but it does not accept the appuser for the signin.
I solved it now by 2 requests to the DB. Not nice but it works. Thank you for trying .

Comment: It is not a good solution. How did you setup Identity in Startup.cs and could you provide AppUser code?